# Can I apply a prototype to a js constructor (as opposed to the instances it creates)?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am attempting to use constructor created objects with prototypes in javascript.

I would like to apply a prototype to the constructor so that any objects it creates inherit the prototype automatically. Is this possible?

I only seem to be able to apply the prototype to individual instances created by the constructor, and not to the constructor itself.

---

I am aiming for something like this:

```
var animal = {
    speak: function(){ console.log(this.name + ' says ' + this.sound); }
}    

var dog = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'bark';
}
dog.__proto__ = animal;

var pig = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'oink';
}
pig.__proto__ = animal;

var percy = new pig("percy");
percy.speak();

var fido = new dog("fido");
fido.speak();
```

The above gives me the error: `percy.speak is not a function`.

It seems that the `__proto__` declaration is not being applied to `pig` or `dog`.

In contrast, it DOES let me apply the `__proto__` declaration to `percy` or `fido` directly:

```
var animal = {
    speak: function(){ console.log(this.name + ' says ' + this.sound); }
}


var dog = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'bark';
}

var pig = function(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = 'oink';
}

var percy = new pig("percy");
percy.__proto__ = animal;
percy.speak();
```

This works, and gives me `percy says oink`, as expected.

Comment: The constructor should be a function, not an animal. Why would you even want that? You *want* animal to be the prototype of the *instances* created by the constructor, not of the constructor itself (`pig.speak()`?!), so just use `dog.prototype = animal` (or `dog.prototype = Object.create(animal)`) like everyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **never use `__proto__`**. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

`__proto__` is a non-standard accessor which should have never existed and may not work if your object does not inherit from `Object.protoype` or `__proto__` has been shadowed. Moreover, changing the [[Prototype]] of an object has a big impact in performance, see the warning in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Second, you are not supposed to mess with [[Prototype]]s when adding methods.

Add them to the `prototype` instead.

```js
var animalProto = {
  speak: function(){ console.log(this.name + ' says ' + this.sound); }
};
var dog = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.sound = 'bark';
};
dog.prototype = animalProto;

var pig = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.sound = 'oink';
};
pig.prototype = animalProto;

var percy = new pig("percy");
percy.speak();

var fido = new dog("fido");
fido.speak();
```

But it would be cleaner using classes:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, sound) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;
  }
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' says ' + this.sound);
  }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name, 'bark');
  }
}
class Pig extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name, 'oink');
  }
}

var percy = new Pig("percy");
percy.speak();

var fido = new Dog("fido");
fido.speak();
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you so much! Is there any chance you could expand (even briefly) on the reason for those two points?  Because I see `__proto__ = ` used a lot on examples elsewhere.